# Get Time In and Time Out from google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am currently trying to write a script to take my users submissions from a google form to sheets then use script editor to create the reservations on a calendar. I have gotten the form portion to work where it dumps the data into a sheet but I am having a hard time with writing the code when it comes getting the the reserved time that the teacher wants to start and then the time that they expect to be done at.

```
// Hanna Springs Reservation
// Adam Fithian

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();




// Creates objects from user submissions
function Submission(){
  var row = lastRow;
  this.date = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
  this.startTime = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
  this.endTime = sheet.getRange(row, 4).getValue();
  this.Location = sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue();
  this.Name = sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue();
  return this;


  }


  //------------main-------------------

function main(){
  var request = new Submission();
  Logger.log(date);
  }
```

[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo4Ut.png)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're shooting for but perhaps this feeble attempt can get you started:

```
function Submission(e){
  var sObj={timesstamp:e.values[0],pickadate:e.values[1],timein:e.values[2],timeout:e.values[3],location:e.values[4],name:e.values[5]};
  var cal=CalendarApp.getCalendarById("id");
  cal.createEvent(sObj.name, sObj.timein, sObj.timeout, {location:sObj.location});
}
```

Comment: I am trying to have my teachers select a date and then select the time they wish to start using the lab on selected day and then put the time that they expect to be done with the lab.

Comment: So you want to present to them some kind of dialog that provides them with a way to select available dates and available times.  Is that correct?